# Python 3 float problems?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, calculation, bignum

I was trying to do the follow calculation in python 3:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5y7z.png

add with:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txoya.png

that should return 0 (images were made in wolframalpha).

When I try to do the same calculation in python:

```
pow((2*3*5),28)-29*math.floor(pow((2*3*5),28)/29)-1
```

it returns `4303955653455607115022335`.

the value of each part is:

`228767924549610000000000000000000000000000` correct.

`-228767924549609995696044346544392884977665` incorrect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include all the relevant code and information as **text** in the question itself, not as external images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: You can fix this by using an actual [tag:bignum] library or [the `fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/fractions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using floating point division `/` which has a limited precision, so your large result gets rounded.

Instead, you can get what you want with integer, floor division `//`, which has an integer result with unlimited precision:

```
import math
pow((2*3*5),28)-29*(pow((2*3*5),28)//29)-1
# 0
```

Comment: really ty was looking for an answer and couldnt find anywhere